# Formatação com UNION e LINQ em C#

Tags: c#, linq, formatação

Eu estou usando o seguinte código para trazer uma lista de empresas com o CNPJ formatado para o DataGridView:

```
dgv.DataSource = db.pessoajuridica
                   .Select(d => new { d.idPessoa, d.nome, d.cnpj })
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(c => new { IdPessoa = c.idPessoa, Razão = c.nome, CNPJ = Convert.ToUInt64(c.cnpj).ToString(@"00\.000\.000\/0000\-00") })
                   .ToList();
```

E estou usando o seguinte código para trazer uma lista de pessoas físicas e jurídicas para o DataGridView:

```
dgv.DataSource = db.pessoajuridica
                   .Select(m => new { IdCliente = m.idPessoa, Nome = m.nome, Tipo = "Pessoa Jurídica", Documento = m.cnpj })
                   .Concat(db.pessoafisica
                   .Select(m => new { IdCliente = m.idPessoa, Nome = m.nome,  Tipo = "Pessoa Física", Documento = m.cpf }))
                   .ToList();
```

Porém eu gostaria que nesta segunda opção também viesse com a formatação, uma específica para o CNPJ e outra específica para o CPF. Mas não está dando certo...

As classes estão definidas a seguir:

```
[Table("pessoa")]
public class pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(90)]
    public string nome { get; set; }
}


[Table("pessoafisica")]
public class pessoafisica : pessoa
{

    [StringLength(11)]
    public string cpf { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string rg { get; set; }

}


[Table("pessoajuridica")]
public class pessoajuridica : pessoa
{

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string nomeFantasia { get; set; }

}
```

Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer?

Valeu!!!

Comment: Por que não usa o `.ToString()` como fez na outra query?

Comment: Porque eu não consigo usar o .ToString() dentro da query... por isso eu coloquei .AsEnumerable() e no próximo select usei o .ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradeço a todos, mas achei a solução.

Na classe pai, adicionei um atributo virtual:

```
[Table("pessoa")]
public class pessoa
{
    [Key]
    public int idPessoa { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(90)]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual string documento { get; set; }
}
```

E dei um override deste atributo nas classes filhas:

```
[Table("pessoafisica")]
public class pessoafisica : pessoa
{

    [StringLength(11)]
    public string cpf { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string rg { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public override string documento
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt64(cpf).ToString(@"000\.000\.000\-00");
        }
    }
}

[Table("pessoajuridica")]
public class pessoajuridica : pessoa
{

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string cnpj { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string nomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public override string documento
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt64(cnpj).ToString(@"00\.000\.000\/0000\-00");
        }
    }
}
```

Limpo, simples e funcional! Fica a solução para quem precisar um dia!

Answer (score 1):

Nesse tipo de caso eu acredito que criar um tipo específico vai resolver, basta fazer a formatação desejada dentro do set da propriedade.

Um exemplo bem básico de como fazer isso:

```
public class ResultadoPessoa
{
    private string _documento;

    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    public string Documento
    {
        get { return this._documento; }
        set
        {
            switch (this.Tipo)
            {
                case "Pessoa Jurídica":

                    this._documento = Convert.ToUInt64(value).ToString(@"00\.000\.000\/0000\-00");
                    break;

                case "Pessoa Física":

                    this._documento = Convert.ToUInt64(value).ToString(@"000\.000\.000\-00");
                    break;

                default:
                    this._documento = value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, sua consulta ficaria:

```
dgv.DataSource = db.PessoaJuridica.AsQueryable()
                                  .Select(m => new ResultadoPessoa { IdCliente = m.IdPessoa, Nome = m.Nome, Tipo = "Pessoa Jurídica", Documento = m.Cnpj })
                                  .Concat(db.PessoaFisica.AsQueryable()
                                  .Select(m => new ResultadoPessoa { IdCliente = m.IdPessoa, Nome = m.Nome, Tipo = "Pessoa Física", Documento = m.Cpf }))
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Oi Diego! Obrigado pela sugestão, mas da forma sugerida recebi o erro "The specified type member 'documento' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." Editei a pergunta e coloquei as classes. Pessoa Física e Pessoa Jurídica herdam a classe pessoa.

Comment: Felipe, não tenho certeza do que ocorre para você estar com esse erro. Criei um projeto no github para ilustar o funcionamento, funcionou normalmente para mim: https://github.com/jeronymo/SOpt_118995

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria isso da seguinte forma..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var Db = new WdbContext())
    {
        GridView1.DataSource =  Db.pessoa
            .Vw_PessoaTipos(Db)
            .ToList();

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WApp.Classes.Banco
{
    public class PessoaTipos
    {
        public rpessoa pessoa { get; set; }
        public rpessoafisica pessoafisica { get; set; }
        public rpessoajuridica pessoajuridica { get; set; }

        public String Documento
        {
            get { return pessoafisica.IdPessoaFisica > 0 ? pessoafisica.cpf : pessoajuridica.cnpj; }

        }

        public String Tipo
        {
            get { return pessoafisica.IdPessoaFisica > 0 ? "Pessoa Física" : "Pessoa Jurídica"; }
        }
    }

    public static class PessoaExt
    {
        public static IQueryable<PessoaTipos> Vw_PessoaTipos(
          this IQueryable<rpessoa> qrIn, WdbContext ctx)
        {
            return qrIn.
                Select(P => new PessoaTipos
                {
                    pessoa = P,
                    pessoafisica = ctx.pessoafisica.FirstOrDefault(PF => PF.IdPessoa == P.IdPessoa),
                    pessoajuridica = ctx.pessoajuridica.FirstOrDefault(PJ => PJ.IdPessoa == P.IdPessoa),
                });
        }
    }
}
```